# Piping images versus sending callback body in node.js with request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request, node-request

I'm using node.js 0.10.33 and request 2.51.0.

In the example below, I've built a simple web server that proxies image using request. There are two routes set up to proxy the same image..

**/pipe** simply pipes the raw request to the response

**/callback** waits for the request callback and send the response headers and the body to the response.

The pipe example works as expected but the callback route won't render the image. The headers and the body appear to be the same.

**What about the callback route is causing the image to break?**

Here is the example code:

```
var http    = require('http');
var request = require('request');

var imgUrl = 'https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/profilephoto/729F00000005O41/T';

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

  if(req.url === '/pipe') {
    // normal pipe works
    request.get(imgUrl).pipe(res);
  } else if(req.url === '/callback') {
    // callback example doesn't
    request.get(imgUrl, function(err, resp, body) {
      if(err) {
        throw(err);
      } else {
        res.writeHead(200, resp.headers);
        res.end(body);
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });

    res.write('<html><head></head><body>');

    // test the piped image
    res.write('<div><h2>Piped</h2><img src="/pipe" /></div>');

    // test the image from the callback
    res.write('<div><h2>Callback</h2><img src="/callback" /></div>');

    res.write('</body></html>');
    res.end();
  }
});

server.listen(3000);
```

Result in this

[image: Test Result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `body` is a (UTF-8) string by default. If you're expecting binary data, you should explicitly set `encoding: null` in your `request()` options. Doing so will make `body` a Buffer, with the binary data intact:

```
request.get(imgUrl, { encoding: null }, function(err, resp, body) {
  if(err) {
    throw(err);
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, resp.headers);
    res.end(body);
  }
});
```

Comment: Super duper. Thanks. I knew it was something simple.